# What technique is mapwow.com using?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I recently came across mapwow.com, and I was impressed with the Google Maps UI on custom content for map tiles.

Did they make this from scratch, or is there some Google Maps API or toolkit?

Comment: ask their developer instead.

Comment: That is not such a bad question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a whole blog post about the making of this map:

http://int2e.com/blog/how-to-make-a-site-like-mapwowcom/

**Edit:** Also, if you look at the page source, at the end, most of the custom tiling code is there..